# I Can't Migrate to Database

Tags: php, laravel

Why can't I migrate to my database? The .env configuration is correct and I created a model in addition to creating the database in phpMyAdmin.

```
php artisan migrate
```

When I run the migrate command I get the following error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access
>   denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL:
>   select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead
>   and table_name = migrations)

Comment: please share `.env` file code here

Comment: can you please share your .evn file DB config data

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dbblog
DB_USERNAME=dbblog
DB_PASSWORD=dbblog

Answer (score 1):

This error basically comes from the after changes in the **.env** file. Whenever we change the `DB_DATABASE`, `DB_USERNAME` and `DB_PASSWORD` in **.env** file, we need to clear the cache.

After completion of .env edit, enter this command in your terminal for clear cache: `php artisan config:cache`

Also, If you are using the PHP's default web server (eg. `php artisan serve`) you need to restart your server after changing your .env file values.

Answer (score 0):

very easy my friend go to  your **.env** file and edit this line to your password

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

DB_PORT=3306
//here
DB_DATABASE=homestead

DB_USERNAME=homestead

DB_PASSWORD=secret

//to here
```

and do

```
php artisan migrate
```